# iPhone NSPredicate how to create a predicate that checks if property has a value?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

This may be a silly question, but until now all of my NSPredicate had some sort of a key given to them:

```
@"SELF.typeRelationship.categoryType != %d";
```

Now I need to create a predicate that would pull all objects from the core data that have a value assigned to them. Any value would do.

Will my predicate look like:

```
@"SELF.typeRelationship.categoryType != 0";
@"SELF.typeRelationship.categoryType != nil";//if an object property?
```

, or **is there some better format that I should use to check if a property has an object assigned to it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this if `categoryType` is a string,

```
NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.typeRelationship.categoryType.length > 0"];
```